# Creating "Empty" version of ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server, versioning

Is it possible to create an "Empty" version of an ArcSDE geodatabase?

I have a large default ArcSDE geodatabase that I would like to create an empty version for a new project.  By "Empty" version I am referring to a version that does not contain any of the information maintained in the default version.  As data populated to this "Empty" version it will be post to the default but never reconciled.  The default serves as an overview of all the data I have worked on but new projects do not have any dependencies upon this data (Typically in vastly different geographic locations).

I really would like to utilize only one geodatabase but am open to input and suggestions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the use case, e.g. what exactly are you trying to accomplish? This doesn't sound like a normal/supported use of versioning.

Answer (score 4):

You can export the schema:

**Copying a geodatabase schema using Extract Data Wizard in ArcMap**

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Copying_a_geodatabase_schema_using_the_Extract_Data_Wizard_in_ArcMap/0093000000t1000000/

**Alternately use the Geodatabase Designer/Diagrammer**

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=F12ADF8F-1422-2418-34B2-C276C6BCCF98